# RStudio "Run Document" not producing an html file

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I've been writing a flexdashboard script in RMarkdown, but the "run document" button does not produce an actual html file, just a preview. The gear box to the right of the "run document" button does not give me the option to produce an html file. It simply says preview in window, preview in viewer pane, or no preview.

The script looks as follows

```
---
title: "dashboard title"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    theme: cerulean
runtime: shiny
---
```

Any help on what is going on would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try "Knit" button. could be on the left side

Comment: adding runtime: shiny removes the knit button from the .Rmd file.

Comment: i mean it removes it from RStudio

Answer (score 0):

You can try `rmarkdown::render_site()` as in this [example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/rmarkdown-site.html) or:

- `knitr::kable()`
- Also you could try `htmltools package`